# Need help applying a uniform max. height across multiple bar charts regardless of max. Y axis value

Tags: excel, charts

I'm not sure if I'm wording that properly, but I would like to have my bar charts all at the same height regardless of the max. value. For example, if on one bar chart my max. value on the Y axis is 7 and the other bar chart the max. value on the Y axis is 10 I would like both bar charts to be the same height. [Here is a reference for what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vInm6.jpg) Notice the chart with a max. value of 10 and the other with 11 have the same height. Any ideas?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a VBA routine to make all of the charts a given worksheet the same height. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Place this routine in a standard code module:

```
Sub EqualChartHeights()
    Const SPEC_TOP = 100
    Const SPEC_HEIGHT = 175
    Dim c
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        c.Top = SPEC_TOP
        c.Chart.ChartArea.Height = SPEC_HEIGHT
        c.Chart.PlotArea.Height = SPEC_HEIGHT
    Next
End Sub
```

Switch to the worksheet with the embedded charts and press Atl-F8 to show the Macro Dialog.

Run `EqualChartHeights`

That's it.

You can manage the height and top values by editing the first two lines.

Note: this technique could easily be expanded to synchronize other chart attributes, such as width, grid lines, tick marks, etc.

**UPDATE**

Based upon your updated requirements, please try the revised procedure below:

```
Sub EqualChartHeights()
    Const SPEC_HEIGHT = 175
    Dim c, p, MaxPoint
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        With c.Chart
            MaxPoint = 0
            For Each p In .SeriesCollection(1).Values
                If p > MaxPoint Then MaxPoint = p
            Next
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxPoint
            .ChartArea.Height = SPEC_HEIGHT
            .PlotArea.Height = SPEC_HEIGHT
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. This made all the chart containers the same height/width, but still when one chart's max value is 10 and another's is 11, it still shows 10 being shorter than 11. Plus, it moved all the charts onto the same row, which doesn't help as this document will be updated multiple times. Thanks though, I feel like I'm getting close...

Comment: I should rephrase and say it's not the SIZE of the chart so much as the SCALE. Size is important too, but the scale is what I'm after. A max value of "3" on one chart should line up with a max value of "10" on another chart.

Comment: Yes, the rephrasing makes all the difference. You asked for size. I will rework for scale. Like I mentioned the same technique can be used for most of the chart attributes. I'll take away the Top property which is what put them all 'on the same row.'